# lastValueFrom throw ObjectUnsubscribedError

Tags: angular, rxjs

In a project with Angular 13 and RxJs 7, I try to use `lastValueFrom` to convert an `Observable` into a `Promise` but it throws an `ObjectUnsubscribedError`.

Here are the specific version of Angular and RxJs:

```
 "@angular/animations": "^13.2.2",
 "@angular/cdk": "~13.2.2",
 "@angular/common": "~13.2.2",
 "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.2",
 "@angular/core": "~13.2.2",
 "@angular/forms": "~13.2.2",
 "@angular/localize": "^13.2.2",
 "@angular/material": "^13.2.2",
 "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^13.2.2",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.2",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.2",
 "@angular/router": "~13.2.2",

 "rxjs": "^7.5.4",
```

The method which is throwing the error:

```js
protected async get<U>(path: string, parameters?: Record<string, unknown>): Promise<U> {
        const url = this.buildUrl(path, parameters);
        const observable = this.http.get<U>(url, { observe: 'response' });
        const promise = lastValueFrom(observable);
        return promise.then((response) => this.onHttpResponse(response) as U);
    }
```

The exception is thrown at

```js
const promise = lastValueFrom(observable);
```

Here is a stacktrace:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ObjectUnsubscribedError: object unsubscribed
_super@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205452:22
ObjectUnsubscribedErrorImpl@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205281:9
_throwIfClosed@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201279:15
_trySubscribe@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201344:12
subscribe/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201033:115
errorContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205520:5
subscribe@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201028:71
subscribe@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:376645:24
onDataLoaded/<@http://localhost:4200/main.js:193468:97
__awaiter/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:283869:71
ZoneAwarePromise@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9546:21
__awaiter@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:283865:12
onDataLoaded@http://localhost:4200/main.js:193462:63
reloadData/<@http://localhost:4200/main.js:190761:20
fulfilled@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:283866:58
invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8322:158
onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:380238:25
invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8322:46
run@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8061:37
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9407:28
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8355:171
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:380226:25
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8355:54
runTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8114:39
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8560:23
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8450:11
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9804:10
globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9847:21
EventListener.handleEvent*customScheduleGlobal@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9993:37
scheduleTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8343:16
onScheduleTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8243:61
scheduleTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8338:43
scheduleTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8162:37
scheduleEventTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8195:21
makeAddListener/<@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10183:27
handle/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:321980:13
_trySubscribe@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201040:21
subscribe/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201033:115
errorContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205520:5
subscribe@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201028:71
catchError/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:202914:23
operate/</<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205814:18
subscribe/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201033:44
errorContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205520:5
subscribe@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201028:71
map/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:203342:12
operate/</<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205814:18
subscribe/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201033:44
errorContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205520:5
subscribe@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201028:71
doInnerSub@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:203425:95
outerNext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:203419:52
OperatorSubscriber/this._next<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:202769:15
next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201482:12
fromArrayLike/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:202390:18
_trySubscribe@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201040:21
subscribe/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201033:115
errorContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205520:5
subscribe@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201028:71
mergeInternals@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:203458:10
mergeMap/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:203497:149
operate/</<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205814:18
subscribe/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201033:44
errorContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205520:5
subscribe@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201028:71
filter/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:203208:12
operate/</<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205814:18
subscribe/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201033:44
errorContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205520:5
subscribe@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201028:71
lastValueFrom/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201863:12
ZoneAwarePromise@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9546:21
lastValueFrom@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201858:10
get/<@http://localhost:4200/main.js:141349:74
__awaiter/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:283869:71
ZoneAwarePromise@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9546:21
__awaiter@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:283865:12
get@http://localhost:4200/main.js:141338:60
current/<@http://localhost:4200/main.js:137456:21
__awaiter/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:283869:71
ZoneAwarePromise@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9546:21
__awaiter@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:283865:12
current@http://localhost:4200/main.js:137455:62
loadData/<@http://localhost:4200/main.js:138483:54
fulfilled@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:283866:58
invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8322:158
onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:380238:25
invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8322:46
run@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8061:37
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9407:28
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8355:171
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:380226:25
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8355:54
runTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8114:39
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8560:23
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8450:11
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9804:10
globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9847:21
EventListener.handleEvent*customScheduleGlobal@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9993:37
scheduleTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8343:16
onScheduleTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8243:61
scheduleTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8338:43
scheduleTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8162:37
scheduleEventTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8195:21
makeAddListener/<@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10183:27
handle/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:321980:13
_trySubscribe@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201040:21
subscribe/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201033:115
errorContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205520:5
subscribe@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201028:71
catchError/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:202914:23
operate/</<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205814:18
subscribe/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201033:44
errorContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205520:5
subscribe@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201028:71
map/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:203342:12
operate/</<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205814:18
subscribe/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:201033:44
errorContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:205520:5
    Angular 2
    rejected tslib.es6.js:74
    Angular 21
    RxJS 35
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    lastValueFrom RxJS
    get base-http-service.service.ts:166
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:76
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:72
    get main.js:141338
    current user-service.service.ts:30
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:76
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:72
    current main.js:137455
    loadData user-connection.component.ts:167
    fulfilled tslib.es6.js:73
    Angular 21
    RxJS 22
core.mjs:6485:12
    Angular 3
    RxJS 6
    Angular 21
    RxJS 35
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    lastValueFrom RxJS
    get base-http-service.service.ts:166
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:76
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:72
    get main.js:141338
    current user-service.service.ts:30
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:76
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    __awaiter tslib.es6.js:72
    current main.js:137455
    loadData user-connection.component.ts:167
    fulfilled tslib.es6.js:73
    Angular 21
    RxJS 22
```

I've been trying multiple things but I fail to understand why this error is thrown. Any idea is welcome.

Thank you for your time.

---

**EDIT 1**

Following @martin advice I found out that if I comment this code inside `onDataLoaded` the error is gone:

```js
this.adiComponents.changes.subscribe(() => {
            this.reloadForm();
        });
```

`adiComponents` is a `QueryList`:

```js
@ViewChildren(AdiComponent) public adiComponents: QueryList<AdiComponent<unknown>>;
```

It's clearly the subscription which is the issue because if I comment the `reloadForm` call the error is still here.

If I understand correctly, this issue happens when their is a change on the `QueryList`. But this is something angular should handle, isn't it ?

Btw `onDataLoaded` is called inside `ngAfterViewInit` in an `async` method.

Comment: It looks like the error comes form your method `onDataLoaded` that tries to subscribe to a Subject that has completed or errored already.

Comment: btw, it looks like the error comes form this line but rather try to look for what subscribes (or awaits) what you return from this `get()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I manage to get a little further in my debugging process but I'm still unable to find what is the root cause of this error. See my edit to get the latest informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I find out what was the issue.

This is a simplified version of my component:

```js
@ViewChildren(AdiComponent) public adiComponents: QueryList<AdiComponent<unknown>>;

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.loadData();
   // Other intializations
}

public async loadData(): Promise<void> {
   this.data = await this.getData();
   await this.onDataLoaded();
}

public async onDataLoaded(): Promise<void> {
    this.adiComponents.changes.subscribe(() => {
            this.reloadForm();
    });
}
```

What happen here is that the component is being destroy before the `loadData` has finish: thus the subscription on `adiComponents` is failing.

In my case the component was destroy because the component is being "recreated" based on outside events.

Hope it could help someone with the same issue.

Comment: A better idea for this use case would be to use for example ngrx, and load data based on the current URL. This way, if the component is destroyed but some state is still being fetched and the component is created again, it wouldn't matter, you'd have your hand on how to load the data (cancel previous and load again to get latest, concat to get the 2 responses one after another, etc)